# Iterate through HTML table using jQuery, converting the data in the table into JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json, html-table

I came across a case where I have to convert an HTML table data into JSON. In this process I have to iterate through the table and convert one by one (row) into an array and then convert the whole array into JSON. How do I iterate through the table (each row and column)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert table into a JSON object in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240005/convert-table-into-a-json-object-in-jquery)

Answer (score 8):

First as fredrik pointed out we need to include https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js.

Second we can use [jQuery.fn.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [jQuery.fn.get](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to create an array of arrays (the `tr`:s) which contains the [jQuery.fn.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) content of the `td` elements:

```
var AoA = $('table tr').map(function(){
    return [
        $('td',this).map(function(){
            return $(this).text();
        }).get()
    ];
}).get();
var json = JSON.stringify(AoA);
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?
Fetching the content of each td into a `myTable[rowIx][tableIx]` array.

```
var myTable = [];
$('#myTable tr').each(function (i, tr) {
    var myTr = [];

    $('td', tr).each(function(j, td) {
        myTr.push($(td).html());
    });

    myTable.push(myTr);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You also need to convert the JavaScript array (also work on objects, strings, etc.) into a JSON serialized string.

Add this to your page (will be added to jQuery soon):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://json.org/json2.js"></script>
```

And then serialize your array:

```
JSON.stringify(myTable)
```