# Convert a HTML table data into a JSON object in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json, html-table

Anyone know how to convert an HTML table of values into a nice JSON object to be manipulated with jQuery?

Comment: What do you mean by "table"? Database table? HTML table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterate through html table using jQuery, converting the data in the table into JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872485/iterate-through-html-table-using-jquery-converting-the-data-in-the-table-into-js)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

An HTML table?  Like, all the `<td>` contents in a 2-d array?

```
var tbl = $('table#whatever tr').map(function() {
  return $(this).find('td').map(function() {
    return $(this).html();
  }).get();
}).get();
```

Then just use $.json (or whatever library you want) to turn that into a JSON string.

*edit* — re-written to use the native ([shim here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility)) `.map()` from the array prototype:

```
var tbl = $('table#whatever tr').get().map(function(row) {
  return $(row).find('td').get().map(function(cell) {
    return $(cell).html();
  });
});
```

The jQuery `.map()` function has the "feature" of flattening returned arrays into the result array. That is, if the callback function returns a value that is itself an array, then instead of that returned array becoming the value of *one* cell of the `.map()` result, its elements are each added to the result.

It *might* work to use the original jQuery version and just wrap an extra array around the returned values.

Comment: The joke here may be that this doesn't really work. The jQuery `.map()` method has the (quite questionable, if you ask me) feature of flattening returned arrays.  This basic approach would work however with the native `.map()` that newer JavaScript environments provide via the Array prototype.

Comment: It is very helpful!! BTW @Pointy, what if very TD has a single class in it, eg <TD class='message'>bah bah bah...</TD>, can I convert it to json, so  class name became property name like that ==> "message" : "bah bah bah...", thanks a lot

Comment: @VirtualJasper yes you could certainly do that, but you'd need to construct an object for each cell. I'd ask a new question.

Answer (score 24):

Do you mean the following situation?

Given:

```
A1 B1 C1 ...
A2 B2 C2 ...
...
```

Needed:

```
{"1": ["A1", "B1", "C1", ...], 
 "2": ["A2", "B2", "C2", ...], ...}
```

So use the following function which creates a valid JSON-String function without trailing ",":

```
function html2json() {
   var json = '{';
   var otArr = [];
   var tbl2 = $('#dest_table tr').each(function(i) {        
      x = $(this).children();
      var itArr = [];
      x.each(function() {
         itArr.push('"' + $(this).text() + '"');
      });
      otArr.push('"' + i + '": [' + itArr.join(',') + ']');
   })
   json += otArr.join(",") + '}'

   return json;
}
```

Comment: this question is 3 years old and has an accepted answer, lol why are you answering it?

Comment: Well, many people will get into same problem as OP. @John's answer may give additional solution for them

Comment: Nice shot, it's amazing.

Answer (score 20):

I needed the same thing except with the ability to ignore columns, override values, and not be confused by nested tables. I ended up writing a jQuery plugin table-to-json:

https://github.com/lightswitch05/table-to-json

All you have to do is select your table using jQuery and call the plugin:

```
var table = $('#example-table').tableToJSON();
```

Here is a demo of it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/Crw2C/173/

Comment: The bad thing is, if there is a html tag within the cell, it will be replaced with empty string.

Comment: @JerryLiang there is an option `allowHTML` to preserve HTML tags

Comment: @lightswitch05 in your jsfiddle if table contains dropdown than how to get only selected value in json ...(In my case senario is same as you said also working fine your fiddle but in my table on more column for State(dropdown) than in json all data given for dropdown.plz help me...Thanks)

Comment: Ghanshyam, don't use this tool to extract form data, use a standard form