# Utilizing Jquery Datatables API in custom map function

Tags: datatables

I want to obtain data from Datatables using its own API functions rather than using regular html table selectors. I m using the editor version too (not shown in the snippets) and I m using the Local table editing feature (I want to batch and send all the data at once)

I tried the following code and it accesses the API data but I can't skip cells.

```
 var data = $('#PrtTbl').find('tr').map(function () {
                return PrtTbl.row(this).data() 
            }).get()
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

**I want to apply** this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290927/how-to-convert-html-table-to-javascript-object-with-jquery) which maps the HTML table and allows me to select certain cells but **The Problem** is that I can't figure out how to access the API stored data,
Only the API functions can give me access to both stored data and hidden columns

```
var tbl = $('#RegSrc tr:has(td)').map(function(i, v) {
var $td = $('td', this);
return {
  RecID: $td.eq(0).text(),
  PtFilenum: $td.eq(1).text(),
  Status: $td.eq(5).text()
} }).get();
```

My target out come would be like this

```
{
"data": {
    "2383": {
        "RecID": 2383,
        "PtFilenum": "15090248",
        "PrtFilenum": 13090701,
        "PrtStatus": ""
    },
    "3387": {
        "RecID": 3387,
        "PtFilenum": "15090248",
        "PrtFilenum": 15120996,
        "PrtStatus": ""
    },
    "3388": {
        "RecID": 3388,
        "PtFilenum": "15090248",
        "PrtFilenum": 170227111,
        "PrtStatus": ""
    }
}}
```

I have this snippet below showing the outcome for both codes

```js
var tablenest = $('#RegSrc').DataTable({
  select: true,
  "bPaginate": false,
  "bFilter": false,
  responsive: true,
  deferRender: true,
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": false,
  bAutoWidth: true,
  data: [{
    "RecID": 2383,
    "PtFilenum": 15090248,
    "PrtFilenum": 13090701,
    "Fullname": " sadden ",
    "PrtStatus": 1
  }, {
    "RecID": 2384,
    "PtFilenum": 15090248,
    "PrtFilenum": 15120996,
    "Fullname": "marwam mohmmad saleem",
    "PrtStatus": 1
  }, {
    "RecID": 2385,
    "PtFilenum": 15090248,
    "PrtFilenum": 170227111,
    "Fullname": "asd dsf a",
    "PrtStatus": 1
  }],
  order: [2, 'asc'],
  keys: {
    columns: ':not(:first-child)',
    keys: [9]
  },
  columns: [{ // Checkbox select column
      data: null,
      defaultContent: '',
      className: 'select-checkbox',
      orderable: false,
      "width": "1%"
    },
    {
      "width": "50%",
      data: "RecID",
      "visible": false
    },
    {
      "width": "50%",
      data: "PtFilenum",
      "visible": false
    },
    {
      "width": "10%",
      data: "PrtFilenum"
    },
    {
      "width": "40%",
      data: "Fullname"
    },
    {
      "width": "10%",
      data: "PrtStatus",
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        if (type === 'display') {
          if (data == 1) {
            return 'Partners';
          } else {
            return 'Not Partners';
          }
        }
        return data;
      },
      className: "dt-body-center"
    },
  ],

});

$("#btn1").click(function() {
  var tbl = $('#RegSrc tr:has(td)').map(function(i, v) {
    var $td = $('td', this);
    return {
      RecID: $td.eq(0).text(),
      PtFilenum: $td.eq(1).text(),
      Status: $td.eq(5).text()
    }
  }).get();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(tbl))
  return false;
})

$("#btn2").click(function() {
  var data = $('#RegSrc').find('tr').map(function() {
    return tablenest.row(this).data()
  }).get()
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
  return false;
})
$("#btn3").click(function() {
  var tbl = $('#RegSrc tr:has(td)').map(function(i, v) {
    return {
      RecID: tablenest.cell(this, 1).data(),
      PtFilenum: tablenest.cell(this, 2).data(),
      PrtFilenum: tablenest.cell(this, 3).data(),
      PrtStatus: tablenest.cell(this, 5).data()

    }
  }).get();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(tbl))
  return false;
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jqc-1.12.4/moment-2.18.1/dt-1.10.15/b-1.3.1/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>



<button id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary">Code1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="btn btn-primary">Code2</button>
<button id="btn3" class="btn btn-primary">Code3</button>
<table id="RegSrc" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed mb-none display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th><b>RecID</b></th>
      <th><b>Patient File Number</b></th>
      <th><b>Partner File Number</b></th>
      <th><b>Patient Name</b></th>
      <th><b>Status</b></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Update**
I added this code and it seems that its working,

```
 var tbl = $('#RegSrc tr:has(td)').map(function(i, v) {
return {
  RecID: tablenest.cell(this, 1).data(),
  PtFilenum: tablenest.cell(this, 2).data(),
  PrtFilenum: tablenest.cell(this, 3).data(),
  PrtStatus: tablenest.cell(this, 5).data()

}  }).get();
```

But I can't still achieve the desired outcome

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got the solution from [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/111538#Comment_111538)

I am posting two codes,
One of them "Code1", works with the table but does not loop through records in pages, whereas Code2 loops through all pages (Pure Datatables API utilization)

```js
var tablenest = $('#RegSrc').DataTable({
  select: true,
  "bPaginate": false,
  "bFilter": false,
  responsive: true,
  deferRender: true,
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": false,
  bAutoWidth: true,
  data: [{
    "RecID": 2383,
    "PtFilenum": 15090248,
    "PrtFilenum": 13090701,
    "Fullname": " sadden ",
    "PrtStatus": 1
  }, {
    "RecID": 2384,
    "PtFilenum": 15090248,
    "PrtFilenum": 15120996,
    "Fullname": "marwam mohmmad saleem",
    "PrtStatus": 1
  }, {
    "RecID": 2385,
    "PtFilenum": 15090248,
    "PrtFilenum": 170227111,
    "Fullname": "asd dsf a",
    "PrtStatus": 1
  }],
  order: [2, 'asc'],
  keys: {
    columns: ':not(:first-child)',
    keys: [9]
  },
  columns: [{ // Checkbox select column
      data: null,
      defaultContent: '',
      className: 'select-checkbox',
      orderable: false,
      "width": "1%"
    },
    {
      "width": "50%",
      data: "RecID",
      "visible": false
    },
    {
      "width": "50%",
      data: "PtFilenum",
      "visible": false
    },
    {
      "width": "10%",
      data: "PrtFilenum"
    },
    {
      "width": "40%",
      data: "Fullname"
    },
    {
      "width": "10%",
      data: "PrtStatus",
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        if (type === 'display') {
          if (data == 1) {
            return 'Partners';
          } else {
            return 'Not Partners';
          }
        }
        return data;
      },
      className: "dt-body-center"
    },
  ],

});

$("#btn1").click(function() {
  var tbl = $('#RegSrc tr:has(td)').map(function(i, v) {
    var myObject = new Object();
    var Data = tablenest.cell(this, 1).data()
    myObject[Data] = {
      RecID: tablenest.cell(this, 1).data(),
      Status: tablenest.cell(this, 5).data(),
    }
    return myObject
  }).get();

  var dt = {}
  dt.data = tbl
  console.log(JSON.stringify(dt))
  return false;
})

$("#btn2").click(function() {
  var tbldta = $.map(tablenest.rows().data(), function(d, i) {
    var myObject = new Object();
    var Data = d.RecID
    myObject[Data] = {
      RecID: d.RecID,
      PrtStatus: d.PrtStatus
    }
    return myObject
  });
  var DtaObj = {}
  DtaObj.data = tbldta
  console.log(JSON.stringify(DtaObj))
  return false;
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jqc-1.12.4/moment-2.18.1/dt-1.10.15/b-1.3.1/se-1.2.2/datatables.min.js"></script>



<button id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary">Code1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="btn btn-primary">Code2</button>

<table id="RegSrc" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed mb-none display responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th><b>RecID</b></th>
      <th><b>Patient File Number</b></th>
      <th><b>Partner File Number</b></th>
      <th><b>Patient Name</b></th>
      <th><b>Status</b></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```