# turn a table into an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a table

```
const header = ["name", "age", "hobby"];
const content = [ ["Eva", 3, "dance"],
                  ["Kevin", 5, "ball"],
                  ...];
```

How can I get output as an array of objects?

```
[{name: "Eva", age: 3, hobby: "dance"}, 
 {name: "Kevin", age: 5, hobby: "ball"},
 ...]
```

Comment: By table, you mean an actual HTML table (and that's just your representation of it's content)?

Comment: My data structure.

Comment: The following link may help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290927/how-to-convert-html-table-to-javascript-object-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Lodash` (or `underscore.js`) library provides some nice functions to transform data. It's just one line:

```
import _  from 'lodash';
const output = content.map((row) => _.zipObject(row, header));
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that the arguments for `row` and `header` should be swapped (`header` coming first).

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this with **javascript** :

```js
const header = ["name", "age", "hobby"];
const content = [["Eva", 3, "dance"],
 ["Kevin", 5, "ball"]
];
const result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
 var obj = {};
 for (var j = 0; j < header.length; j++) {
  obj[header[j]] = content[i][j];
 }
 result.push(obj);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

can be done with map and reduce

```
const header = ["name", "age", "hobby"];
const content = [
  ["Eva", 3, "dance"],
  ["Kevin", 5, "ball"]
];

console.log(content.map((item) => {
  return header.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
    acc[cur] = item[i];
    return acc;
  }, {});
}));
```