# Collect data from html table use jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, collect

I need collect data from the HTML table and send it to the server. I must use JQuery.
there is my table

```
    <table id="table" border=1>
    <thead> <tr>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Last</th>
    <th>Date of birth</th>
    <th>City</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>TEXT1</td>
    <td>TEXT2</td>
    <td>TEXT3</td>
    <td>TEXT4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>TEXT5</td>
    <td>TEXT6</td>
    <td>TEXT7</td>
    <td>TEXT8</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>TEXT9</td>
    <td>TEXT10</td>
    <td>TEXT11</td>
    <td>TEXT12</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: What data do you want to collect?

Comment: u have to go thgh previous questions before asking one here

Comment: Have you gone through the basics of how to use jquery? Accessing elements, and their values? You might be better served by going through the documentation.

Comment: I need collect all data from td tag (each cell).

Comment: Dear ryadavilli thank you for comments. I will follow for them, but I don't have a time right now for looking docs. I will do it in any case later and read more about basics of how to use jquery. But please just help me do this task now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve it in this manner,

First we select all the data from the table cell's and then we send it to the server side via jquery ajax

***JQuery Code:***

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var dataArr = [];
    $("td").each(function(){
        dataArr.push($(this).html());
    });
    $('#sendServer').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
              type : "POST",
              url : 'server.php',
              data : "content="+dataArr,
              success: function(data) {
                  alert(data);// alert the data from the server
              },
              error : function() {
              }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

***Html code:***

```
<table id="table" border=1>
    <thead> <tr>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Last</th>
    <th>Date of birth</th>
    <th>City</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>TEXT1</td>
    <td>TEXT2</td>
    <td>TEXT3</td>
    <td>TEXT4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>TEXT5</td>
    <td>TEXT6</td>
    <td>TEXT7</td>
    <td>TEXT8</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>TEXT9</td>
    <td>TEXT10</td>
    <td>TEXT11</td>
    <td>TEXT12</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>

<input id="sendServer" name="sendServer" type="button" value="Send to Server" />
```

in your server side ***PHP Code*** (here i am sending back what has been posted to server, just for the example)

```
<?php 
echo $_REQUEST['content'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

possible duplicate of [convert a HTML table data into a JSON object in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240005/convert-a-html-table-data-into-a-json-object-in-jquery)

but solution is

```
var tbl = $('table#whatever tr').map(function() {
  return $(this).find('td').map(function() {
    return $(this).html();
  }).get();
}).get();
```

Then just use $.json (or whatever library you want) to turn that into a JSON string.