# Converting Html Table to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've created a sample application which converts html table into JSON. The problem is that the JSON is not having duplicate values also i want to remove the last two columns from the JSON.

My JSON which has been generated is given below

```
[
   {
      "Person Name":"Smith",
      "Score":"disqualified",
      "Price":"150",
      "Tax":"41"
   },
   {
      "Person Name":"Jackson",
      "Score":"94",
      "Price":"250",
      "Tax":"81"
   },
   {
      "Person Name":"Doe",
      "Score":"80",
      "Price":"950",
      "Tax":"412"
   },
   {
      "Person Name":"Johnson",
      "Score":"67",
      "Price":"750",
      "Tax":"941"
   }
]
```

But my expected JSON is like

```
[
   {
      "Person Name":"Jill",
      "Person Name":"Smith",
      "Score":"disqualified"
   },
   {
      "Person Name":"Eve",
      "Person Name":"Smith",
      "Score":"94"
   },
   {
      "Person Name":"John",
      "Person Name":"Smith",
      "Score":"80"
   },
   {
      "Person Name":"Adam",
      "Person Name":"Smith",
      "Score":"67"
   }
]
```

Can anyone please tell me how to generate the above JSON from the table

My code is as given below.

**html code**

```
<table id='example-table'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Person Name</th>
        <th>Person Name</th>
        <th data-override="Score">Points</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Tax</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td data-override="disqualified">50</td>
        <td>150</td>
        <td>41</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
        <td>250</td>
        <td>81</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>80</td>
        <td>950</td>
        <td>412</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>750</td>
        <td>941</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="convert-table" >Convert!</button>
```

**javascript code**

```
$('#convert-table').click( function() {
  var table = $('#example-table').tableToJSON();
  console.log(table);
  alert(JSON.stringify(table));  
});
```

[**DEMO (JSFiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/cCzqn/80/)

Comment: There is a key named `Person Name` twice. ["The names within an object SHOULD be unique."](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

Comment: Like this?? http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/xAh4T/

Comment: to ignore the last two columns : `tableToJSON({ignoreColumns:[3, 4]});`

Comment: @alexP but i need both.....is there any solutions for that

Comment: @RobertRozas no both Person Names are different....should need duplicate Person Names with different values

Comment: @RobertRozas your code code for removing last two columns works fine good

Comment: Or this?? http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/cCzqn/82/

Comment: @RobertRozas no both should be Person Name

Comment: I wrote a open source web page for this here http://tools.fromdev.com/table-to-json-converter.html - the source code is in github here https://github.com/fromdev/tools/blob/master/table-to-json-converter.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a HTML table data into a JSON object in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240005/convert-a-html-table-data-into-a-json-object-in-jquery)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

something like that would work (not really nice, but)

Explanation :

You can use ignoreColumns to avoid taking columns 3 and 4.

You can use headings to change the "headers" (keys in the json file). But this will take also the first line (the one with the TH).

So we have to remove that first line after building the json array.

```
$('#convert-table').click( function() {
    var $table = $('#example-table');

    var table = $table.tableToJSON(
                      {
                         ignoreColumns:[3, 4], 
                         headings: ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Score']
                       });
    var newTable = $.map(table, function(e){
        return (e.FirstName == "Person Name") ? null : e;
    });
    console.log(newTable);
    alert(JSON.stringify(newTable));  
});
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cCzqn/80/)

**EDIT**

If the number of columns with Person Name is dynamic, you could do something like that (assuming you never want the two last rows)

```
function convertToTable(el, numberOfColumns, columnNames) {
    var columnsToIgnore = [numberOfColumns-2, numberOfColumns-1];
    var table = el.tableToJSON(
        {
            ignoreColumns:columnsToIgnore, 
            headings: columnNames
        });
    var result = $.map(table, function(e){
        return (e['Person Name0'] == "Person Name") ? null : e;
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
}

$('#convert-table').click( function() {
    var $table = $('#example-table');
    var columns = $table.find('th');
    var numberOfColumns = columns.length;    
    var columnNames = columns.map(function(index) {
        var text = $(this).text();
        return text == 'Person Name' ? text + index : text;
    }).get();

  convertToTable($table, numberOfColumns, columnNames); 
});
```

see [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cCzqn/84/)

Comment: the problem is that the columns Person Name is dynamic, can be two or more than that

Comment: @user3253853 than you'll have to build your own function which will be calling the tableToJSON with the right parameters.

Comment: @user3253853 by the way, could you show some "different cases" which could exist ?

Comment: None of your fiddles work. Missing the `tableToJSON `

Answer (score 4):

You can't have duplicate keys, but you can use an array of names instead. Example:

```
{
  "PersonNames":["John","Smith"],
  "Score":"80"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

to remove last two fields use "ignoreColumns" option

```
var table = $('#example-table').tableToJSON({
    ignoreColumns:[2,3]
});
```

and make headers unique

```
<th>Person Name</th>
<th>Person SurName</th>
```

Comment: Thanks ..... this works in removing the last two columns....but how about to generate JSON with duplicate key (Person Names) with different values

Comment: I don't think this module is intended to do that. You would need to use another module that allows it, if you can find any that does.

Comment: tableToJSON is a jquery module. anyway, why do you need to have duplicate column names so badly? maybe this restriction can be lifted by another means?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#convert-table').click( function() {
var table = $('#example-table').tableToJSON({
    ignoreColumns:[3,4]}
);
 console.log(table);
 alert(JSON.stringify(table));  
});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/9VX6Z/

Comment: its not First Name Last Name, it should be Person Name

Answer (score 0):

From row a way to format html-data.

```
$("#del_player").on("click", function() {
    var row_to_del = $("#table_player tbody tr[active=true]");
    var arr = [];

    $.each(row_to_del, function(key, val){
        arr.push(val.outerText.split('\t'));
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
})
```