# parse html table to json jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to convert html table to json data? i need result like this. Code must be on jquery

```
{"status":"ok","data":[{"name":"Haroldas","number":444,"address":"address"},{"name":"tom","number":999,"address":"rrr"},{"name":"ted","number":333,"address":"kkk"}]}
```

here is my table:

```html
<table id="excel">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th>name</th>
      <th>number</th>
      <th>address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">Haroldas</td>
      <td>444</td>
      <td>address</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1">ted</td>
      <td>333</td>
      <td>kkk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">tom</td>
      <td>999</td>
      <td>rrr</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT: here is jquery code, but not exactly because in table are thead

```
$.makeTableToArray = function () {
    var table = $('#excel tr').map(function() {
        return $(this).find('td').map(function() {
            return $(this).html();
        }).get();
    }).get();

    return table;
};
```

thank you

Comment: show us your effort !!

Comment: Can you show us a bit of your JS code ?

Comment: Duplicated??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461102/converting-html-table-to-json

Comment: no its not dublicated. there is my jquery:

    $.makeTableToArray = function () {
        var table = $('#excel tr').map(function() {
            return $(this).find('td').map(function() {
                return $(this).html();
            }).get();
        }).get();
        
        return table;
    };

i cant add more code to post

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```js
$.fn.toJson = function(){
  
  if(!this.is('table')){
    return;
    }
  
  var results = [],
      headings = [];
  
  this.find('thead tr th').each(function(index, value){
    headings.push($(value).text());
    });
  

  this.find('tbody tr').each(function(indx, obj){
    var row = { };
    var tds = $(obj).children('td');
    headings.forEach(function(key, index){
      var value = tds.eq(index).text();
      row[key] = value;
      });
    results.push(row);
    });
  
  return results;
  }

$(function(){
  $('#results').html(JSON.stringify($('#excel').toJson(), null, '\t'));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="results"></pre>
<table id="excel">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th>name</th>
      <th>number</th>
      <th>address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">Haroldas</td>
      <td>444</td>
      <td>address</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class="sorting_1">ted</td>
      <td>333</td>
      <td>kkk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">tom</td>
      <td>999</td>
      <td>rrr</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To use:

```
  $('tableSelector').toJson();
```

It's up to you to add those keys besides the table data.