# How convert a HTML table data into a JSON object in jQuery Without using any plugin.?

Tags: jquery, json

Anyone know how to convert an HTML table of values into a nice JSON object (Without using any plugin like `jquery.tabletojson.min.js`) to be manipulated with jQuery? If you can explain it in a fiddle it'll be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this SO.

```
var tbl = $('table#whatever tr').map(function() {
  return $(this).find('td').map(function() {
    return $(this).html();
  }).get();
}).get();
```

Using shim here

```
var tbl = $('table#whatever tr').get().map(function(row) {
  return $(row).find('td').get().map(function(cell) {
    return $(cell).html();
  });
});
```

A possible duplicate of this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240005/convert-a-html-table-data-into-a-json-object-in-jquery).