# convert jquery datatable data as json

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I am using jquery data table. I have a table like below,

```
<table id="employees">
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
           <td>1</td>
           <td>Karthik</td>
           <td>Kk@gmail.com</td>
           <td>1234</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>1</td>
           <td>Karthik</td>
           <td>Kk@gmail.com</td>
           <td>1234</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I am converting the table into jquery datatable as `$('#employees').DataTable()`

I want to convert my jquery datatable as json format.
Please help me to convert this as

```
[{"Id":"1", "Name":"Karthik","Email":"kk@gmail.com","Phone":"1234"}]
```

Comment: Hi Praveen Kumar, Thanks for the reply. No I want to convert the entire rows as json.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert a HTML table data into a JSON object in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240005/convert-a-html-table-data-into-a-json-object-in-jquery)

Comment: May this helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240005/convert-a-html-table-data-into-a-json-object-in-jquery?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @Karthikeyan Check my answer. Run snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you need to get the column values:

```
var heads = [];
$("thead").find("th").each(function () {
  heads.push($(this).text().trim());
});
```

This will give you:

```
["Id", "Name", "Email", "Phone"]
```

Using this we can loop in each row and get the values:

```
var rows = [];
$("tbody tr").each(function () {
  cur = {};
  $(this).find("td").each(function(i, v) {
    cur[heads[i]] = $(this).text().trim();
  });
  rows.push(cur);
  cur = {};
});
```

So finally you would have:

```js
var heads = [];
$("thead").find("th").each(function () {
  heads.push($(this).text().trim());
});
var rows = [];
$("tbody tr").each(function () {
  cur = {};
  $(this).find("td").each(function(i, v) {
    cur[heads[i]] = $(this).text().trim();
  });
  rows.push(cur);
  cur = {};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<table id="employees">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Karthik</td>
      <td>Kk@gmail.com</td>
      <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Praveen</td>
      <td>pp@gmail.com</td>
      <td>5678</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

**Output: http://jsbin.com/kuhuzivadi/edit?html,js,console,output**

Comment: but it returns first page records only. I have pagination in that table, so it returns first 10 records. Can you please help on this.

Comment: @Karthikeyan Lemme see if there's something on the datatables API. Give me some time. Hey, btw, are you using DT using AJAX or just converting it using DT? Static load or remote load?

Comment: not thru Ajax Praveen. The table will be populated by iterating the data and rendering it.

Comment: @Karthikeyan Appo super. Give the code before you call `dataTable()` on it. `:)` I bet it works. `:D`

Comment: @Karthikeyan *Machi enna paathu en da paarangallu nu sonne?* `:P`

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I am using the same thing and facing the same problem. Can you please tell me what you did to resolve it? I am not sure what you guys communicated.

Comment: @NiteshJoshi Happy to look through any [mre] if you have got. Please tell me.

Answer (score 11):

Try using DataTable rows function

```
 $('#YourDataTableID').DataTable().rows( { search: 'applied' } ).data().toArray();
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   // Let's put this in the object like you want and convert to JSON (Note: jQuery will also do  this for you on the Ajax request)
   alert(JSON.stringify(tableToJSON($("#employees"))));
});


function tableToJSON(tblObj){  
   var data = [];
   var $headers = $(tblObj).find("th");
   var $rows = $(tblObj).find("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
   $cells = $(this).find("td");
   data[index] = {};
   $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
     data[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $(this).html();
   });    
});
  return data;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="employees">
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
           <td>1</td>
           <td>Karthik</td>
           <td>Kk@gmail.com</td>
           <td>1234</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>2</td>
           <td>Karthik</td>
           <td>Kk@gmail.com</td>
           <td>4567</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Karthikeyan check my answer.

Comment: @Karthikeyan Run Snippet. You will get `list`.

Comment: Hi Parth Trivedi, Thanks for your reply. It works.. You are rock.

Comment: @Karthikeyan can i get my credits? Its a more generic way. Only have to call `tableToJSON` function. :)

Comment: @Karthikeyan you should change question title. My answer is it can be apply to all `html` table not only datatale. It can be more helpful in future for others.

Comment: this is working only if we have static data in the table. i got some input elements and the code is copying the enitre html input tag as part of json

Comment: It works only for 1st page (10 records). I'm using datatable pagination. How to do for all the pages?

Comment: @Waseem. I have the same issue and still trying to figure out the solution. Have you got any solution for the pagination problem?

Comment: @NiteshJoshi, yes I got the solution.

Comment: @Waseem, can you please point me to the solution? I am still stuck with it.

Comment: @NiteshJoshi here is the code for reading all data of the data table. 
**function convertTableToArrayObject() {

    var transactions = [];
    var table = $('#transactionsList').DataTable();
    var data = table.rows().data();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        transactions.push(data[i]);
    }
    return transactions;
}**

Comment: @Waseem, I tried using the code, it yes definitely gets all the values but its getting the whole html element and not just values.

Comment: @NiteshJoshi yes it is. What do you want from the data table? I mean do you need whole data or some specific column values of the data table?

Comment: @Waseem this is the code I am using: 
    function tabletoJSON(tblObj) {var data = [];var count = 0;var $headers = $(tblObj).find("th"); var $rows = $(tblObj).find("tbody tr").each(function (index) {
            $cells = $(this).find("td"); data[index] = {};
            $cells.each(function (cellIndex) {if (cellIndex == count) {
                    data[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $('input', this).attr('value');
                } else {data[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $(this).text();}});});return data;}
This gives me exactly header name and value for each cell.

Comment: @Waseem I need all the data from all the columns and the headers as well. Also my table has input boxes so that the user can update the values within the table itself and then send out the updated data to backend, and then I convert that to json and then feed it to my mssql script.

Answer (score 4):

```
var employees = convertTableToArrayObject();
alert(JSON.stringify(employees));
```

```
function convertTableToArrayObject() {

    var employeeObjects = [];
    var table = $('#employees').DataTable();
    var data = table.rows().data();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        employeeObjects.push(data[i]);
    }

    return employeeObjects;
}
```

- **function convertTableToArrayObject:**
  loop on each row of data table, and add to array objects
- **JSON.stringify(employees):**
  convert the array objects to json