# Create new array based on user-edited table values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of this form:

```
[ [1,"item1","oldvalue1"] , [2,"item2","oldvalue2"] , [3,"item3","oldvalue3"] , ... ]
```

And I am displaying it like this:

```
 name  |   default_value  |  new_value 
------- ------------------ -----------
item 1 |     oldvalue1    |   oldvalue1

item 2 |     oldvalue2    |   oldvalue2

item 3 |     oldvalue3    |   oldvalue3
```

At first, I want the NEW_VALUE column to show the default values for each item 
(these are the "old" values from the original array).

But I want the cells in this 3rd column to be editable. 
For example, in this case, I chose to edit the values for item 1 and item 3, item 2 remains with the oldvalue it had before.  After editing my cells, I would get this:

```
 name  |   default_value  |  new_value 
------- ------------------ -----------
item 1 |     oldvalue1    |   newvalue1

item 2 |     oldvalue2    |   oldvalue2

item 3 |     oldvalue 3   |   newvalue3
```

And then from this final table, I want to be able to get an array like:

```
[ [1,"item1","newvalue1"] , [2,"item2","oldvalue2"] , [3,"item3","newvalue3"] , ... ]
```

I am looking to get some ideas on how to implement this. I am unsure on what I should do next.

What I need help with is

1. how to make the 3rd column editable ( I was thinking of using a plugin called Jeditable...)
2. how to building the array from table values...

Thanks for your help. I was unsure on how to name this post, if you think I should change it to something more helpful please let me know.
THANKS

Comment: That's because so far I only show a table...I just want an overall idea on how I would get this done, not code line by line...

Comment: For both #1 and #2, we need your table structure and what you have already tried.

Comment: #2 is something that's relatively easy, you just select all rows and loop through them generating an array of data from the row's cells. Not a whole lot of guess work there. #1 on the other hand depends on what the data is and how you wish to edit it.

Comment: I don't see anything that we can actually help you with... You already know what you need to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Table to an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231310/convert-table-to-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I coded an example made with jQuery using the `data` functions:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nescalante/PgMpA/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer looks good. Thanks for your time, Im glad I got a couple good answers :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make the third column editable would be an `<input type="text" />` form field, this would also make clear that it is editable.

To build the array you can use `.each()` combined with `$(selector, column)` (column being your currently iterated column), so there is just searched for elements matching the selector inside of the current column.

I also would you recommend to wrap your data into extra tags to seperate it from your labels, for example in the first column:

```
<td>item <span>1</span></td>
```

This way you do not need to seperate the data from the value via string manipulation.

See also: http://api.jquery.com/each/, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ (have a look at the context parameter)

Comment: Thank you for your time and your answer. I appreciate any help I get from this website. Ill give this a shot, I just needed some hints to get started.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to mock-up a sample of what it sounds like you're looking for:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>item 1</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td><input  size="3" value="5"></input></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
     <td>item 2</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td><input  size="3" value="6"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>item 3</td>
     <td>7</td>
     <td><input size="3" value="7"></input></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="CA" value="Create Array"></input>
```

`input`s were added in the last `td` of each `tr` to make the content *editable* in that column. Also notice that I'm initially setting these values. When you set the old value, you can do so in the `input`s as well so that the old value is loaded into the text box.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on("click", "#CA", function(){ //when the button is clicked
  var array = []; //array to hold the changed information
  $("tr").each(function(i){
    array.push([i, 
                $(this).children("td:eq(0)").text(), //get the text from the first td
                $(this).children("td:eq(2)").children("input").val()]); //get the value from the last td's input
  });
  console.log(array);
});
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cqpTT/)**