# Convert HTML Table Element to JSON via data attributes

Tags: jquery, json, html

I'm new to jQuery!

Is there a way to convert table element data to JSON? see sample image below.

[image]

The JSON result was on the `#result` div.

Comment: Check here: [Iterate through HTML table using jQuery, converting the data in the table into JSON][1]

Although if you yourself control the generation of this table, I'd recommend something like knockout (http://knockoutjs.com/)

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872485/iterate-through-html-table-using-jquery-converting-the-data-in-the-table-into-j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = $('tr').map(function () {
    var o = {
        "apvhdrid": this.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.apvhdrid,
        "id": this.dataset.id
    };
    $('td', this).each(function () {
        for (key in this.dataset) {
            o[key] = this.dataset[key];
        }
    })
    return o;
}).get();

$('#result').text(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pE8Hu/

Comment: magic! thank you for that! 
this is what i needed to do this! http://goo.gl/jX5hL